# Problems testing XHRs/Fetch with Chrome 42 on OS X

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest, reactjs, fetch

We are using Marty.js (and React.js) in our webapp.
As I read in the [Marty.js docs](http://martyjs.org/api/state-sources/http.html) they're using the fetch-polyfill to communicate with the server over `http`. Everything fine so far ...

While testing in Google Chrome (currently v42) first I noticed that the `body` of the request isn't shown (but sent ?!?) and then that I can't "replay XHR" from the dev-tools.

**Can anybody tell me why this is the case?**

[image: screenshot of chrome's devtools]

*update 04/26/15*
Because it seems to not have anything to do with marty.js I removed it from the question's title.

Comment: Reproduce: https://gist.github.com/aronwoost/116c17f9d98ae2c61eb7

Comment: Ergo: not marty/flux/react related.

Comment: Resources with type Fetch (not XHR) cannot be replayed. Even though the filter called XHR says 'XHR and Fetch' when you hover over it. I filed a feature request (although I believe it was just a not fully implemented feature): https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597400

Comment: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=573371

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're seeing is related to two issues in MartyJS' github.

https://github.com/martyjs/marty/issues/308 (success function called regardless off http status code returned)

https://github.com/martyjs/marty/issues/293 (martyjs not deserialzing json properly in certain browser setups) <-- this is the one you're having a specific issue with it looks like.

There was an update to the library to fix both of these. I recommend upgrading. We haven't had any problems since grabbing the latest as of a week ago (0.9.14). I believe a new version has already been released (0.9.15) while work on 0.10 is being done in parallel.

Comment: as Aron mentioned in the comments - this problem is reproducable using the standard `fetch` syntax in chrome - so I'm pretty sure it has nothing to do with marty itself. but will try and update all the same ;)